# Wordpress : Redirect Wordpress attachment URL

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

Is anyone able to Redirect the following permalink URL for me?

The URL that WordPress is: http://example.com/?attachment_id=411

I would like to redirect it to new structure i do it, The following code not work with me in old URL:-

```
/* add new rewrite rule */
function attachment_rewrite( $wp_rewrite ) {
    $rule = array(
        'media/(.+)' => 'index.php?attachment=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1)
    );

    $wp_rewrite->rules = $rule + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
add_filter( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'attachment_rewrite' );

/* redirect standard wordpress attachments urls to new format */
function redirect_old_attachment() {
    global $wp;

    if( !preg_match( '/^media\/(.*)/', $wp->request ) && isset( $wp->query_vars['attachment'] ) ) {
        wp_redirect( site_url( '/media/' . $wp->query_vars['attachment'] ) , 301 );
        exit();
    }
}
add_filter( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_old_attachment' );
/**/
function wpd_attachment_link( $link, $post_id ){
    $post = get_post( $post_id );
    return home_url( '/media/' . $post->post_name );
}
add_filter( 'attachment_link', 'wpd_attachment_link', 20, 2 );
```

So we  need when open `http://example.com/?attachment_id=411` , redirect it to `http://example.com/media/post-title`

Comment: Elaborate your question with more details, such as the input and the output structure.

Comment: i need when open `http://example.com/?attachment_id=411` , redirect it to `http://example.com/media/post-title`

Answer (score 0):

Update your existing code to following,

```
//Modify attachment page link
add_filter( 'attachment_link', 'wp_attachment_link', 20, 2 );
function wp_attachment_link( $link, $attachment_id ){
    $attachment = get_post( $attachment_id );
    $attachment_title = $attachment->post_title ;
    $attachment_title = str_replace( ' ' , '-' , $attachment_title );
    $site_url = get_site_url( $attachment_id );
    $link =  $site_url . '/media/'  .$attachment_title;
    return $link;
}
// Rewrite attachment page link
add_action( 'init', function() {
    add_rewrite_rule( 'media/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$', 'index.php?attachment_id=$matches[2]', 'top' );

} );
```

I hope this helps.